# PHP - Maximum Execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, database

sometimes I get the script execution error, where it takes over 30 seconds. It's always in my connector file. Could you have a look pelase and let me know if you say anything obvious...

I'm on a VPS so I have full control of the server so I can make any required changes.

```
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$uTime = time();
$uDate = date('Ymd',$uTime);
$onlineLimit = 1800;
$activeLimit = 3628800;
$fDate = date('Ymd', strtotime('next monday'));
$time_start = microtime(true);

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx") or die("Could not connect.");
if(!$db) 
die("no db");
if(!mysql_select_db("xxxx",$db))
die("No database selected.");
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
  $_GET = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET); 
  $_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST); 
  $_COOKIE = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_COOKIE);
}
else
{  
   $_GET = array_map('stripslashes', $_GET); 
   $_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST); 
   $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes', $_COOKIE);
   $_GET = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET); 
   $_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST); 
   $_COOKIE = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_COOKIE);
}
  mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'")or die(mysql_error());

  $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  $season = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`start`,`end` from `season` order by `id` DESC limit 0,1"));
  $seasonDays = round((strtotime($season['end'])-strtotime($season['start'])) / 86400);
  $currentDay = ceil(($uTime - strtotime($season['start'])) / 86400);
```

Comment: Any ideas what line it dies on?

Comment: Is the error fairly easy to reproduce? If so, I would put echo statements at various point in the file to help determine what line is timing out. they can be as simple as `echo "step 1"`, `echo "step 2"`, etc.

Comment: Nothing in that code should be causing a timeout... is that all of your code?

Comment: @MarkBaker One of the SQL queries is probably the issue.

Comment: It seems to fallover if I have a large amount of page refreshes.

Comment: @MrGlass it shouldnt be, as its intermittent.

Comment: @MarkBaker thats the whole file that does it. Nothing is called before that file.

Comment: Are you able to check the resources your using on the vps? SI the processor or RAM spiking? what about Disk I/O?

Comment: Ah thanks, its the Proc/RAM, time to double it all :)

Comment: This is a very vague "Please check my code" problem. What have you tried to isolate the problem? When you run the sql queries directly in the database, how long do they take to run? Does this always happen or does it seem to vary with some other parameter (time of day, server load, etc)? What does the error log show?

Comment: @MrGlass - Neither the set charsets, nor the select (for one record) should take a long time to execute.... db is on localhost, so minimal network overhead... unless `season` is unindexed, and has millions of records, they shouldn't cause problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would set higher max_execution time in php.ini and you will see where it will die...

Answer (score 4):

add `set_time_limit(0);` to the top of your code, it will allow it to run without time constraints.

**UPDATE** to be safe as mentioned in the comments bellow set x in `set_time_limit(x);` to the max number of seconds of execution. 0 = infinite

Comment: I've voted up, but theres no real answer... I would personally recommend against setting limit as 0 (infinate) as scripts can then run for ever if you make an endless loop. Thanks for the answers

Comment: Set to 0 would be bad indeed. Up voting because set_time_limit() is the least intrusive method to modify execution time limit since it can be done inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it in a .htaccess file at the root of your site with:

```
php_value max_execution_time 3600
```